# Where to change highlight color for selected occurrences in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When a method or variable is selected it is highlighted in Eclipse with some color. Can anyone advice where to change that color? I'm working under Windows OS.

Comment: The menus are slightly different for Each Platform. Are you using Mac OSX, Linux, or Windows?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I've found where to change it:

Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations
and there you have to change both "Occurrences" and "Write occurrences".

Comment: It's good to note that for each language you'll have a different set of "Occurrences" and "Write occurrences". At least in my case with C/C++, Python and Java.

Answer (score 16):

Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors

Current Line Highlight

I think you want the above

else

Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring

Element -> Java -> Method or Variable

Check Enable and select color

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. I'm interested in the color which is using to highlight a method or a variable when one of those are selected by means clicking on it.

Answer (score 2):

This has made me mad for about half an hour.

If the issue appears in JavaScript files, the option is under Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations and in the Annotation types choose JavaScript Occurences. Mine was set to black, nasty little thing took me too long to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using eclipse with PHP package and want to change highlighted colour then there is slight difference to above answer.

1. Right click on highlighted word
2. Select 'Preferences'
3. Go to General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations. Now look for "PHP elements 'read' occurrences" and "PHP elements 'write' occurrences". You can select your desired colour there.

[image: Change Highlighted text colour in Eclips with PHP]