# Change highlight color for fields in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

[image: Poorly grabbed screenshot of the Eclipse window]

I'm using Eclipse EE Neon (4.6.3) and would like to know **how to change the highlight color in the `Find` field**; right now it's the same as the background and it is complicated to edit the searched string. I'm guessing this is only a problem in the default dark theme, which I'm using. I looked at other answers but they were about changing other colors such as the [highlight of search results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4699166/3399416).

Comment: The Dark theme has been improved in Oxygen.0 and Oxygen.1. Can you reproduce this issue after [upgrading to Oxygen.1a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250)?

Comment: Thanks for responding; I'd rather not upgrade unless there's a guaranteed easy transition of all the metadata the IDE is holding (Maven, project configurations, etc), so I would prefer a current version alternative if it exists. Otherwise I'll just live with this minor annoyance.

Comment: I haven't had such problems with any update yet. But to be sure (especially if you use third-party plug-ins), make a backup or test the new version with a new workspace (and import the projects from the existing workspace). [Here (Oxygen.0)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-cO9wZj6w) and [here (Oxygen.1a)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8) you can see what improvements you would miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [Darkest Dark](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle) plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace solved this issue for me; it differentiates the selection in the search field unlike the Eclipse default dark theme at that time.

Maybe the newer Eclipse versions have a dark theme without this problem, but I haven't checked.