# Change highlight color for fields in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse

[image]

I'm having the same problem described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970244/change-highlight-color-for-fields-in-eclipse). Essentially I can't find a way to change the highlight color of the Find/Replace field in Eclipse and the current highlight color is the same as the field color, making it difficult to see what is selected. In the original post someone mentioned updating Eclipse, and I can confirm that upgrading will not help. I'm running Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) and have the exact same problem. I'm in Ubuntu 17.10 and have tried installing different GTK themes, different Eclipse themes, and different Color Themes (via Eclipse Color Theme plugin), non of which change the background or highlight colors of this field.

Comment: This post is quite old but the issue does seem to be fixed in Ubuntu 18.04 and Eclipse 4.10.0